# Making an external monitor appear "bigger" in display preferences

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, system-settings, display

I have an external 27" display connector to my 14" MacBook Pro. This is what I see in the Display section in System Preferences:

[image]

macOS seems to think that my 27" monitor is only slightly larger than my 14" built-in screen, which clearly isn't the case. As a result, mouse transfers from one monitor to another aren't scaled properly and feel unnatural.

Is there any way to make the external monitor here "bigger" with relation to the internal monitor, so that mouse transfer from one screen to another will scale properly?

Comment: Display prefs is concerned only with screen resolution. Physical size is not considered at all.

Comment: Interesting... so if I connect a 48" 4K OLED TV it'll show up as the same size?

Comment: You should align either the top or the bottom of these two monitors.  Having them offset like that makes the mouse discontinuity worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display sizes you see on the figure you have provided is scaled according to the UI resolution of the display, not the native resolution or the physical size of the display.

14" macbook pro built-in screen native resolution is 3024x1964, and since MacOs uses 4 pixels to render 1 UI pixel, it looks like half of that: 1512x982. This is the UI resolution.

If your 27 inch monitor is a full HD monitor, it's resolution will be 1920x1080p, which is slightly bigger than macbook pro built-in screen UI resolution.

If your 27 inch monitor is a 4K monitor and you did not change any settings for the UI resolution, MacOs is still probably using 4 pixels to render 1 pixel, so it still uses a UI resolution of 1920x1080. Text and everything will look sharper compared to a full HD display. However, since your UI resolution is the same, your screen real-estate will be the same as a 1920x1080 full HD display. And the external display will still look small in the figure you have provided.

If you are using a 4k display, you can use the scaled UI resolution 2560x1440. In that case, the text size and UI element sizes will be more closer to the size in built-in display, you will have much more screen real-estate, and finally you will see a larger display in the figure you provided compared to the built-in display.

Scaled resolutions put some burden on the GPU in terms of performance, but that will probably be a breeze for the GPU of M1 Pro. Additionally, the text rendering will not be as sharp as the non-scaled default resolution, but it will please most of the users. You should try and see if it is acceptable for you. I own the same laptop, and I use my 27" 4K monitor like that, and I am quite happy with the setup.